# Increase Java's Computational Abilities

Tags: java, eclipse, math, equation, capacity

So I'm not sure exactly if this is a problem of Eclipse, Java, or my computer. What I'm trying to do is basically *2^57885161-1*. But, sadly, all that Eclipse outputs is "Infinity". My deduction is either that Java sets a limit to the maximum of a computed equation, Eclipse does, or that my Computer cannot handle the amount of computational ability it would require.

If it is Java or Eclipse, is there a way that I can remedy the situation?

Thank you.

Comment: Why???? Getting 7Mb of `0xFF` should not be sooooo complicated...

Comment: The answer is 17million+ digits long, so you know...

Comment: Sure. Or to be precise - "integer" represented in binary as 7235645 bytes with value 0xFF. Still very interesting why do you need that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the java.math.BigDecimal (or java.math.BigInteger) class for extremely large numbers.

What's probably happening is that you're using an int or a double, and that number is MUCH too large for those datatypes in Java. Using BigDecimal, which can be arbitrarily long, will solve your problem given time.

**edit** - previously I had written "java.util.BigDecimal", which is the wrong package.

Comment: Note that you'll still fill 17MB with this number alone.

Comment: I believe this will work, but given the size of the requested number, I'm sure it'll take a very long time to equate. Thank you for the response. I was totally unaware of this awesome package!

Comment: Yeah. It'll take an extremely long time to do that calculation. Since you know it's going to be all ones however, there's a shortcut: you could fill a byte[] with the requisite number of 0xff 's and then use the BigInteger's byte[] constructor. That would be somewhat faster, but it'll still be pretty unwieldy.